# Mathematical Drawings,sketch like (Geometry)

Tags: software-recommendation, mathematics

I'm a mathematics student doing a thesis project related to geometry and I want to add some pictures, I have no experience in graphic design but I really want my project to look aesthetically pleasing.

I'd like to know which software suits me better. I was using TikZ package in LaTeX but its not worth it.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on the style of the drawing I would suggest any vector editor software such as Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics_editor

Comment: What about the learning curve of Inkscape for my purposes ?  The examples I gave are quite more complicated than what I'm going to do

Comment: I Would suggest mathematica if you can demonstrate basic usage im sure mathematica.se will help you as a matter of pride, if you provide function to plot. They are even nicer than GD.SE if such thing can be possible.

Comment: It is hard to suggest a tool without knowing what you want to do exactly. I would think, though, that if you are familiar with geometry then learning to use a vector editor would be more intuitive than learning to use a raster editor such as Photoshop.

Comment: I can add more pictures if you need them. Just ask.

Comment: Sure, if you show us what you need exactly it would be easier. The main idea will be the same, though. If you need to build your image out of geometric forms and manipulate them as separate entities, then use a vector editor. If you need to manipulate the pixels of your image (colour transitions, funky effects, filters, realistic textures, etc) then use a raster editor.

Comment: I added  a torus. The idea is that I'm doing quite an abstract project and I want some pics to make things more intuitive and pleasing to read. I want to make it look clear and have a feeling of handmade stuff. I won't be manipulating things much it's just something like "All this abstract non-sense looks like this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum. This question can be just a simple software recomendation, but here we go.

Asumming you already have the basic correct shape generated (for example this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28mathematics%29

You can import them as a bitmap into:

Inkscape https://inkscape.org/es/

and Draw Plus Starter http://www.serif.com/free-graphic-design-software/

The reason of theese two is becouse are 2 good free programs, but second they have **node based curved lines** that are esential to edit your work.

In the industry the leader is Ilustrator and second Corel Draw, but they are payed ones. You will do fine with either of the 2 mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to use [LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/). It's not quite as advanced as something like Illustrator, but it's easy to use, and it offers important basics such as grids and individual vertex manipulation.

Here's some examples I did with it:

[image]
[image]

(only the logo of the second, not the background)